# Show Different UI elements when selecting TreeView Items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am new with WPF - I want to create a tester for my server
I want to have on the right side of the application a TreeView and whenever a user selects a node - appropriate items is shown on the right side. For example I have a Connection node and under it many Sessions nodes, The Connection and Session have different parameters. I have built the tree view using mvvm and all works fine, but how can I achieve the second goal?

the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Tree1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self ="clr-namespace:Tree1"
    xmlns:models ="clr-namespace:Tree1.Models"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:TestPlanViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:ConnectionViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Connection" Margin="10, 0, 0,0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:SessionViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock  Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Session"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Button Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="277,10,144,0" Name="addSessionBtn" Width="76"></Button>

    <TreeView Name="testPlanTview" Margin="0,10,283,0" SelectedItemChanged="testPlanTview_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" Header="Test Plan">
        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post the most significant parts of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataTemplates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). There are two possible solution for your problem.

First of all let's create a base class:

```
public abstract class SelectableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool isSelected;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For our example we have two classes:

- Car, whose properties are "Hp" (int) and "Matriculation" (DateTime)
- Person, whose properties are "Name" (string) and "Surname" (string)

Both of them extend `SelectableObject`.
Now the ViewModel (of course it is just a sample):

```
public class ViewModel : SelectableObject
{
    private ArrayList tree = new ArrayList();
    private ObjectWrapper current;
    private Car car = new Car();
    private Person person = new Person();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        car.Hp = 120;
        car.Matriculation = DateTime.Today;
        car.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnItemPropertyChanged);

        person.Name = "John";
        person.Surname = "Doe";
        person.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnItemPropertyChanged);

        tree.Add(car);
        tree.Add(person);
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectableObject impl = (SelectableObject)sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected" && impl.IsSelected)
        {
            Current = new ObjectWrapper(impl);
        }
    }

    public ObjectWrapper Current
    {
        get
        {
            return current;
        }
        private set
        {
            current = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Current");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable Tree
    {
        get
        {
            return tree;
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel uses a the `ObjectWrapper` class:

```
public class ObjectWrapper
{
    private readonly object wrappedInstance;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyWrapper> propertyWrappers;

    public ObjectWrapper(object instance)
    {
        Collection<PropertyWrapper> collection = new Collection<PropertyWrapper>();
        Type instanceType;

        wrappedInstance = instance;
        instanceType = instance.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in instanceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            collection.Add(new PropertyWrapper(instance, propertyInfo));
        }

        propertyWrappers = new ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyWrapper>(collection);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyWrapper> PropertyWrappers
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyWrappers;
        }
    }

    public object Instance { get { return wrappedInstance; } }
}

public class PropertyWrapper
{
    private readonly object instance;
    private readonly PropertyInfo propertyInfo;

    public PropertyWrapper(object instance, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
    }

    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
    }

    public Type PropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
        }
        set
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

***First solution (the easiest one)***
You can use implicit datatemplating:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">

    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>


        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Current.Instance, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
                    ... define your car template here ...
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                    ... define your person template here ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

***Second solution (imho the best one)***
You can take advantage of `ObjectWrapper` object, by using an `ItemsControl` (here I used [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) for DateTime and Int controls):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemTemplateSelector" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <toolkit:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <toolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Current.PropertyWrappers, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Margin="5" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The implementation of the `ItemTemplateSelector` it is not difficult:

```
public class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        PropertyWrapper propertyWrapper = (PropertyWrapper)item;
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)container;
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.TryFindResource(propertyWrapper.PropertyType);

        return dataTemplate;
    }
}
```

My answer is quite long, but I wanted to show you both roads you can use.
Of course you can improve the `PropertyWrapper` by using attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using MVVM i would sugest something like System.Windows.Interactivity and Prism regions to implement what you need.

For example:
Xaml:

```
 <TreeView Name="testPlanTview" Margin="0,10,283,0">
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" Header="Test Plan">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenNewViewCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=testPlanTview}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TreeViewItem>

</TreeView>
  <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MyRegion"/>
```

Viewmodel:

```
 public ICommand OpenNewViewCommand
        {
            get { return this.selectedCommand; }
        }
```

In the view model constructor you add:

```
  this.selectedCommand = new DelegateCommand<YourModel>(this.SelectedExecute);
```

And the command:

```
  private void SelectedExecute(YourModel parameter)
{
 this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MyRegion, new Uri("ViewToNavigate", UriKind.Relative), parameters);
}
```

Please be aware that this is **just an example** on how to make the navigation possible with prism.
 For more information on what i'm suggesting you can check the msdn link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430881%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)