# Generating TextBoxes to fill in a class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have several classes that need to have their properties filled in. For example:

```
class RecordType1
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set;}
}

class RecordType2
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public float Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

For RecordType1 I would like to generate a `DatePicker` to fill in Date and two `TextBox` to fill in both the `Name` and the `Value`. Likewise for RecordType2 I would like a `DatePicker` and three `TextBox` for `Name,`Location`, and`Temperature`.

I could create a file containing a separate `UserControl` per class that has the required TextBlocks and TextBoxes but it seems as if there could be a better way to generate a form for the user to fill in.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: I answered to a very similar question some minutes ago. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167631/show-different-ui-elements-when-selecting-treeview-items/29175797#29175797)

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way to do this in WinForms is to use a PropertyGrid control. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent in WPF, but you could [host the PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control using a `WindowsFormsHost`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that via reflection. You start by getting the type:

```
Type typeinfo = typeof(RecordType1);
```

you can then iterate through the attributes.

If you don't want to do all this yourself you can use exceeds propertygrid.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Interstone.Bestelbonnen.Views.DrawingPropertiesControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Interstone.Bestelbonnen.ViewModels"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<xctk:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding}" AutoGenerateProperties="False" IsCategorized="False">
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

more info on the propertygrid :
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid

I did not elaborate too much on the reflection part, I am not sure which direction you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Its certainly *possible* to do what you are asking, even at runtime. You would use reflection to get the various fields and then generate controls to match the field types.

Now, this isn't a very *practical* approach, especially considering the high likelihood that such a generated form's layout is likely to be terrible. The normal approach is to just create the forms/user controls manually.

Since you are in WPF, a good approach is to use Data Templates instead of user controls, as you can easily use them in `ItemsControl`s and `ContentControl`s